# How to set and call a prototype method during instantiation

Tags: javascript, oop, object, constructor

I keep getting the error 'validate is not a function'

```
function someObj( nameOfObj ) {
    this.nameOfObj = nameOfObj;
    var create = '<input id=' + nameOfObj + '>';
    document.write(create);


    someObject.prototype.validate = function(  ) {
        //nonsense
    }

    jQuery( '#' + this.nameOfObj ).bind( 'input', function(  ) {

        this.validate(  ); //or validate(  ); <------- Not working here

    } );    

}
```

I want to create an object that is a self validating `<input>` as the user types, it will execute `valitdate(  )` and I want to bind this validation during instantiation.

Comment: where definition of someObject and why you use document.write?

Comment: Before you dive into JS you should master DOM and HTML elements. (??`'<input></input>'`??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using an old version of JQuery? Since version 1.7 the on method is preferred to [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

You don't have provide the validate function in the constructor function, my guess is that you can't get it to work because `this` in the bound function refers to the Element. Here is how you should do it:

```
function someObj( nameOfObj ) {
    this nameOfObj = nameOfObj;
    //there are better ways of doing this: 
    // http://api.jquery.com/?s=append
    var create = '<input id=' + nameOfObj + '></input>';
    document.write(create);
    var me = this;
    jQuery( '#' + this.nameOfObj ).bind( 'input', function(  ) {
        me.validate(  ); //or validate(  ); <------- Not working here

    } );
}
someObject.prototype.validate = function(  ) {
    console.log("and this is now:",this);
    //nonsense
}
```

Introduction to constructor functions, prototype and the value of `this` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941).

Comment: I didn't know about JS scope binding until your response. Here is an article that describes it fairly well for anybody having the same problem. http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/04/28/binding-scope-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Is the use of the prototype really needed? It just seems to work in this way:

```
function someObj( nameOfObj ) {
    this.nameOfObj = nameOfObj; //changed here
    var create = '<input id=' + nameOfObj + '></input>';
    document.write(create);


    this.validate = function(  ) { //changed here
        //nonsense
    }

    jQuery( '#' + this.nameOfObj ).bind( 'input', function(  ) {

        this.validate(  ); //or validate(  ); 

    } );    

}
```

Comment: The `this` value of `this.validate` is an Element object not a someObj object.

Comment: but when I print that "this" to the console, I have an instance of someObj
// CODE //
 this.validate = function(  ) { //changed here
        //nonsense
    };
console.log(this);

Comment: If you run the following on this page (in the console) and click on a code block then it'll log the element: `jQuery( 'code' ).bind( 'click', function(  ) {
  console.log("and this is:",this);
});  `